# MPAndroidChart: getColors() is now deprecated for 'Legend'. What should I use instead?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm displaying a custom legend for a PieChart in MPAndroidChart however, .getColors() and .getLabels() are now deprecated.

I've been using them to get an int array and string array respectively but I can't seem to find a direct alternative. Am I missing something obvious? What should I now use instead? Thanks!

```
Legend legend = mChart.getLegend();
legend.setEnabled(false);

if (legend.getColors() != null) {

    int colorCodes[] = legend.getColors();
    String labels[] = legend.getLabels();

    ArrayList<LegendItem> legendItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < legend.getColors().length-1; i++) {
        legendItems.add(new LegendItem(colorCodes[i], labels[i]));
    }

    showLegend(legendItems);

    // entry label styling
    mChart.setDrawEntryLabels(false);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Legend` class now follows better OOP practices and is composed of an array of `LegendEntry`. You can iterate through each and extract the colors or the labels as you wish.

```
private int [] getColors(Legend legend) {
    LegendEntry [] legendEntries = legend.getEntries();
    int [] colors = new int[legendEntries.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < legendEntries.length; i++) {
        colors[i] = legendEntries[i].formColor;
    }
    return colors;
}

private String [] getLabels(Legend legend) {
    LegendEntry [] legendEntries = legend.getEntries();
    String [] labels = new String[legendEntries.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < legendEntries.length; i++) {
        labels[i] = legendEntries[i].label;
    }
    return labels;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!