# MPAndroidChart Pie Chart Custom Legends are not displaying correctly

Tags: firebase, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I have create piechart using MpAndroidChart and data is retrieved from firebase.I need to display custom legends but only one item is displaying but pieChart has more than 5items.Since getColor() and getLabels() are deprecated and i have used [this Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236779/mpandroidchart-getcolors-is-now-deprecated-for-legend-what-should-i-use-in) to get color and label of piechart

```
listdataref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d("TAG", "IF else");
                /* new homePieTask().execute(dataSnapshot);*/

                ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    int total = ds.child("total").getValue(Integer.class);
                    String name = ds.child("expensesName").getValue(String.class);
                    entries.add(new PieEntry(total, name));


                }

                pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(entries,"Expense By Dates");
                pieData= new PieData(pieDataSet);
                homepiechart.setData(pieData);
                pieDataSet.setColors(color);
                Legend legend = homepiechart.getLegend();
                legend.setEnabled(false);
                int colorCodes[] = getColors(legend);
                String labels[] = getLabels(legend);
                for (int i = 0; i < getColors(legend).length -1; i++) {
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms_legen_layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            20, 20);
                    parms_legen_layout.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 0);
                    LinearLayout legend_layout = new LinearLayout(context);
                    legend_layout.setLayoutParams(parms_legen_layout);
                    legend_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    legend_layout.setBackgroundColor(colorCodes[i]);
                    relativeLayout.addView(legend_layout);

                    TextView txt_unit = new TextView(context);
                    txt_unit.setText(labels[i]);
                    relativeLayout.addView(txt_unit);
                }
```

Comment: Can Some one please help me. i was struck in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i done this by Following Code and i dnt know this is best method or not but still it works good

```
 listdataref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Log.d("Grid","On");
                List<String> labelsList=new ArrayList<>();
                if (getActivity() != null) {

                        Log.d("Grid", "OnOn");
                        for(int i=0;i< dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();i++) {
                            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                String label = ds.child("expensesName").getValue(String.class);

                            labelsList.add(label);
                                List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                                for (int j : color)
                                {
                                    intList.add(j);
                                }


                                aClass = new LegendsClass(intList.get(i), labelsList.get(i));

                        }

                            legendsClasses.add(aClass);
                            gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), legendsClasses);
                            gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
                            gridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                        Log.d("Grid", "After");
                    }


                }
                }else
            {
                Log.d("Grid","else");
                gridView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```